# How to show ContextMenu in custom class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am learning wpf technology. I have created such custom class, which should react on mouse up event (should show popup menu)

```
public class CustomControl : UIElement
{
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs args)    
    {
         ContextMenu context_menu = new ContextMenu();
         // How to show context_menu at specific point?
    }
};
```

I don't know how to show created context menu at speficic position. It don't have specified Show method. UIElement don't have appropriated ContextMenu property

Edit: I am not using XAML (I don't want create dependency between source code and design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WPF you would design a context menu in XAML usually. A brief tutorial of how to do that is [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html) for example.

Basically you write your context menu within the respective control and use `Command`s or mouse events like `Click` to assign a specific behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, that tutorial helped me (I thought that IsOpen property only accessed via get method)

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко most properties of controls that can be changed by user interaction are setable in WPF. While you can realize everything without ever touching the XAML, it is far easier usually to use it.